# How insert display none correctly

Tags: javascript, html, css

I do not know exactly what happens I used the following example to build my slide:

https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_slideshow_dots

It is working, but the images with none display are misaligned, as I'm clicking the next image it goes down a bit down

first slide

[image]

last slide

[image]

my code is exactly the same as the example

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentDiv(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex = n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  if (n > x.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = x.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  x[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";      
}
```

```css
.mySlides {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<div class="w3-content" style="max-width: 800px;">
  <img class="mySlides" src="1.png" style="width: 100%;" />
  <img class="mySlides" src="2.png" style="width: 100%;" />
  <img class="mySlides" src="3.png" style="width: 100%;" />
  <img class="mySlides" src="4.png" style="width: 100%;" />
  <img class="mySlides" src="5.png" style="width: 100%;" />
  <img class="mySlides" src="6.png" style="width: 100%;" />
  <img class="mySlides" src="7.png" style="width: 100%;" /></div>
<div class="w3-center">
  <div class="w3-section">
    <button class="w3-button w3-light-grey" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">❮ Anterior</button>
    <button class="w3-button w3-light-grey" onclick="plusDivs(1)">Próximo❯</button></div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you put this into a jsfiddle or something that would help us to figure out what's going on.

Comment: There's no `class="demo"` in your HTML. What's supposed to be in `dots`?

Comment: @Barmar Sorry, I actually removed the dots, but I tested it now and with or without them the same thing happens.

Comment: It's not related to the problem, but makes it harder for us to run the code you posted.

Comment: If you remove the dots from the HTML, remove the JavaScript that refers to them.

Comment: @Andrew—no, the code should be here.

Comment: This isn't XML, so the forward slash in `<img ... />` is just junk. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that you don't have any space between the last `<img>` and `</div>`.

Your last image is like this:

```
<img class="mySlides" src="7.png" style="width: 100%;" /></div>
```

But in the w3schools demo it's like this:

```
  <img class="mySlides" src="img_mountains_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
</div>
```

Because of this, there whitespace after all the other images, and this shows up as space between the image and the prev/next buttons.

Comment: That was it! Thank you so much Barmar